# How to list every loop of forEach to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to the results of my `forEach` loop one by one as a list on HTML for which I have used :

```
object = {
food1 : [potato, tomato, carrot]
}

object[food1].forEach(function (item){
    var text = "";
    text += item;
    $("#ulelement").html("<li>" + text + "</li>");
})
```

Currently this resulting in adding a list element to my html featuring the last run of the forEach which is " carrot "
What I would hope to achieve is for it to give me 3 list elements:
potato
tomato
carrot

Comment: It's a little hard to know what is actually being asked here. Please edit your question and be more clear on what is not working and how do you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `.html()` you overwrite the effect of the previous iteration, and so you only get the last value in the output.

You could use `.append()`:

```
$("#ulelement").append("<li>" + text + "</li>");
```

Side note: it is better to use jQuery to the full, to avoid character encoding problems:

```
$("#ulelement").append($("<li>").text(text));
```

To reset the list at the start, add this *before* the loop:

```
$("#ulelement").empty();
```

Comment: This has also worked to the aim perfectly however only reason .reduce served me better is because I am in need of it to be replaced when I change the value. Regardless thank you so much this is also another new thing for me!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want `ulelement` to contain all the created `li` elements not just the last one, if that is the case, you can use `.reduce`, here is an example:

```
ulelement.html(object[array].reduce((a, c) => `${a}<li>${c}</li>`, ""))
```

You can find more details about `.reduce` [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Also, I've used a template literal in this example, you can find details about that [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Spot on sir! this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you ! I will need to educate myself with how it worked also. Thank you